# connect to postgres rds instance with pycharm db manager

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, pycharm

I am struggling to connect with pyCharm to a postgres instance running on amazon rds.

In `host` I plug in the Endpoint. I configure driver to be the jdbc jar file (external library).

Test connection says that the connection on port `5432` is refused: `Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.`

On rds side:

- For the security group I have an inboud rule for `All traffic` with source `Anywhere`
- The VPC has DNS resolution and DNS hostnames enabled
- VPC is publicly accessible
- VPC `classic link` is enabled

Comment: Did you find the reason it wasn't connecting? I have the same problem.